# OnClick function sends multiple ajax requests when(atleast attempted to) designed for one request

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason when I click on the 'Next' button once it's sending 7 requests to the flask server. And the requests are urls for the next 5 values,

Example:
url1:'/result?limit=5&offset=0'
returns data, next_url:'/result?limit=5&offset=5'(it should stop here

```
Extra:
url2:'/result?limit=5&offset=5'
returns data, next_url:'/result?limit=5&offset=10'

url3:'/result?limit=5&offset=10'
returns data, next_url:'/result?limit=5&offset=15'
```

The above keeps repeating until somehow on the 8th url returned `next onclick`  is stored as `onclick=undefined` and then stops working.

HTML:

```
<button id='Next' onClick= "next('/result?limit=5&offset=0')">Next</button>
```

JS:

```
function next(url)
{
    console.log('abskd')
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'GET',
        dataType:"json",
        // data:JSON.stringify([{"offset":0,"limit":5}]),
        contentType:"application/json",
        url:url,
        success: function(result)
        {
            console.log(result)
            displayTable(result['data'])
            document.getElementById('Next').setAttribute('onclick', next(result['next']));
            // document.getElementById('Previous').setAttribute('onclick',change_page(result['prev']));
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You should NEVER use set attribute for event listeners. Next issue, you are calling next() and assiging what it returns to the attribute

Comment: O, is there a reason as to why not? @epascarello

Comment: because that is what addEventListener is for

Comment: Well I need to set the value for a new request to be sent when I click on next

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding an event to the onclick attribute, you are binding what the function call returns. So that is your first issue.

Just bind the event once. Just keep track of the index in the function

```
document.getElementById('Next').addEventListener('click', function() {
  next(1);
});
document.getElementById('Previous').addEventListener('click', function() {
  next(-1);
});

const currentIndex = 0;
const limit = 5;

function next(direction) {
  if (currentIndex <= 0 && direction === -1) return;
  currentIndex += direction;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      "offset": currentIndex * limit,
      "limit": limit
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/result",
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
      displayTable(result['data'])
    }
  });
}

next(0); // load first page
```

If you have different urls you want to load, then it can be done with a bit more code where we keep track of indexes by url instead of just one global.